# authenticate bigquery javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, google-identity, google-api-javascript-client

I am putting together a web app where I would like to display some bigquery data on my webpage

However, I am having trouble setting up the authentication for bigquery's javascript api. Most of the examples and resources, including Google's own [docs](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/auth.md) dont make use of the new [Google Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview).

So far I have html that looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="client.requestAccessToken();">Authorize me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="interaction.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and javascript that looks like

```
//authorize
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: 'my_id',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
    callback: (tokenResponse) => {
        if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.access_token) {
            console.log("token response")
            gapi.client.load('bigquery', 'v2', sendQuery)
        }
    },
});

//query
function sendQuery() {
    let request = gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query({
        'query': "SELECT h3_id FROM `...` limit 10",
        'timeoutMs': 30000,
        'datasetId': "my_dataset",
        'projectId': "my_project",
        'useLegacySql': false
    });
    request.execute(response => {
        console.log(response)
    });
}
```

*Ive replaced clientid and BQ parameters with placeholders for this stack post.*

From what I can tell, the code doesn't run past gapi.client.load('bigquery', 'v2', sendQuery). But strangely I am not getting any errors in developer's console - making this hard to debug. Am I missing an additional step in the auth?

I have loosely been trying to follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/maps-platform/bigquery-maps-api#0) but adapt it with Google's [Identity Services](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load gapi client with `gapi.load('client')` before using `gapi.client`.

I could make your code work by adding:

```
gapi.load('client');
```

at the very top of you javascript (before `const client = ...`)

Comment: This is the simple solution I was looking for. Can confirm this works. I also posted an alternative approach I made work in the meantime. But I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish authenticating to bigquery starting from the basic example in the Google Identity migration guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#the_new_way)

My code now looks like:

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="initClient()" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="interaction.js"></script>
    <h1>Google Identity Services Authorization Token model</h1>
    <button onclick="getToken();">Get access token</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="queryBigQuery();">Query BQ</button><br><br>
    <button onclick="revokeToken();">Revoke token</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```js
var client;
var access_token;

function initClient() {
    client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: '....',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly \
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery \
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
                https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only',
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
        },
    });
}

function getToken() {
    client.requestAccessToken();
}

function revokeToken() {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {
        console.log('access token revoked')
    });
}

// make post request to bigquery api
function queryBigQuery() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', `https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/${project_id}/queries`);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    const requestBody = {
        query: "...",
        useLegacySql: false
    };

    //results 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
            console.log(xhr.responseText)
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(requestBody));
}
```

The difference from the original post is that the access token generated in callback is passed to the global access_token variable and then used in the header of a standard XMLHttpRequest.  Still not sure how to make this work with gapi..